# Por que a condição de j nunca é satisfeita com "||", e porque o i é satisfeito com "&&"?

Tags: java

```
package aulas;
   public class Aula{
     public static void main(String[] args){
       for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < 100 || j < 50; ++i);
          //Quando troco o operador lógico para && é impresso até 99, porém
          //quando uso || é impresso até o infinito(ou estouro da variável)
  }
}
```

Comment: Você está modicando j em algum lugar? e qual seu valor de inicio

Comment: O valor de j = 0. Desculpa, já fiz a correção!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A questão é a seguinte, você está incrementando apenas o valor da variável `i`. Deste modo ela irá variar de `0` até `99`.

Estas são as tabelas verdade para os conectivos lógicos:

**E (&&)**

```
A | B | A && B
--+---+-------
V | V | V
V | F | F
F | V | F
F | F | F
```

**OU (||)**

```
A | B | A || B
--+---+-------
V | V | V
V | F | V
F | V | V
F | F | F
```

Deste modo, como pode ser visto no operador `OU (||)` as duas condições precisam ser falsas para que o loop pare. Como o valor da variável `j` nunca é incrementado. O loop é infinito causando assim o estouro.

Já no operador `E (&&)` apenas uma das avaliações precisa ser falsa para tornar a expressão booleana falsa, e assim interromper o loop, fato que ocorrerá apenas quando o valor de `i` for 100.

Answer (score 1):

Porque o valor de `j` está estático.

Vc tem apenas o `i++` assim `j` sempre atenderá a condição proposta